# vuejs 3 I deleted folder node_modules and now npm install has error

Tags: vue.js, npm-install

I have a work project, but I deleted folder node_modules and now npm install has error.

node v16.13.2
@vue/cli 4.5.15

my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "3.4.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.4.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.8",
    "@ionic/vue": "^6.0.9",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^6.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.21",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.16.5",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
```

npm install

```
# npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: dev.infi.loc@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^7.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@">= 1.6.0 < 7.0.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.17
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"~4.5.15" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-27T14_01_53_031Z-debug.log
```

How can I fix it? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Error screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmLtI.png

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me a while ago, i dont know if the solutions is still going to work but, tried deleting the package.json then use `npm init` hen run dependency-check in your project directory followed by a npm install

Comment: I didn't understand what it was for. maybe I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me was upgrading `@vue/cli-plugin-eslint` to `^5.0.4` (The `^` means "up to next major").

On a side note, you should keep all your packages as up-to-date as possible for security reasons.

Comment: thaks, but in this case, there is a new error when launching the application.  
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'NormalModule')  
screenshot [link](http://joxi.net/5mdkb8wI3G4vdr.jpg)

Comment: The main problem with npm is that the developer may simply stop supporting the library. It's even worse when a developer makes changes that can radically change the logic and break the project at an unexpected moment.

Comment: For example, like now. I have updated the packages to the latest versions. And now I get the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: api.now is not a function` [link to screenshot error](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2022/03/29/0004/1703/325287/87/cb56c80d4a.jpg)

Comment: Whenever you upgrade a package to the next major, it's a good idea to look at a migration guide to avoid any trouble. 
I don't know what api is, so I can't help you there. But for your initial question, it got resolved. This one deserves its own separate post.

Comment: Orijhins, thank you for your help, but I did it. Upgraded version of packages, time after time. Deleting folder node_modules and upgraded browser. In the end everything worked out. Sorry for my English.